# Insert into table consecutive DateTime values every 5 secounds

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, while-loop, datetimeoffset

Say I have a table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    CreatedAt   DAteTimeOffset  NULL
);
```

How can I insert into that table 500 row in a `while` loop and have each date every 5 secound ? I want my outcome result be like this :

```
2018-10-08 05:00:00.0000000 +00:00
2018-10-08 05:00:05.0000000 +00:00
2018-10-08 05:00:10.0000000 +00:00
2018-10-08 05:00:15.0000000 +00:00
2018-10-08 05:00:20.0000000 +00:00
2018-10-08 05:00:25.0000000 +00:00
2018-10-08 05:00:30.0000000 +00:00
2018-10-08 05:00:35.0000000 +00:00
2018-10-08 05:00:40.0000000 +00:00
2018-10-08 05:00:45.0000000 +00:00
2018-10-08 05:00:50.0000000 +00:00
2018-10-08 05:00:55.0000000 +00:00
2018-10-08 05:01:00.0000000 +00:00
2018-10-08 05:01:05.0000000 +00:00
2018-10-08 05:01:10.0000000 +00:00
2018-10-08 05:01:15.0000000 +00:00
```

and so on ...

I have a while loop here but I don't know how to achieve inserting consecutive rows with values every 5 sek.

```
DECLARE
    @i int = 0

WHILE @i < 500
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table1
    (CreatedAt)
    VALUES
    (?)
END
```

Comment: This is a great candidate for using a ["tally table"](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)

Comment: select datetimefromparts(2018, 10, 12, 10, 22, 5, 0) and just replace the numbers by variables. But using a tally table would be indeed better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use set-based approach. It's usually much faster:

```
WITH N AS --generate 500 rows (1..500)
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) N
    FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) A(A)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) B(B)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) C(C)
)
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, (N-1)*5, SYSDATETIME()) FROM N
```

If you really, really need a loop (discouraged), you can use following:

```
DECLARE @i int = 0;
DECLARE @d DAteTimeOffset = SYSDATETIME();
WHILE @i<500
BEGIN
    INSERT table1 VALUES (@d);
    SET @d = DATEADD(second, 5, @d);
    SET @i += 1;
END
```

Comment: This is a good answer. Just a side note: Instead of specifying all these values, you can simply do `select top 500 row_number() over (order by @@spid) from sys.objects` (and if it's a small database, add a cross join: `sys.objects a cross join sys.objects b`

Comment: `sys.objects`, is alright, but with a small dataset as this will require IO to disc (to get the list of objects), where as a (virtual) tally table can completely be done in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I think Zohar means this solution

```
declare @t table (CreatedAt datetime)

insert into @t 
select top 500 
       dateadd(second, (row_number() over (order by @@spid ) - 1) * 5, sysdatetime()) 
from   sys.objects 
  --cross join sys.objects a cross join sys.objects b 

select * from @t
```